# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException (No implementation found for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have been working on a Flutter projects where I have to use my own Platform Channel which has been implemented in AppDelegate and Activity.

Then now I am trying to use a plugin and when ever that plugin is called, it shows "Missing Plugin Exception". My local platform channel works good, however it's the iOS platform and plugins that does not work.

Comment: Split out your platform channel code into a plugin of your own, and import that into your main project by depending on it in pubspec.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrongly, accessed the FlutterViewController so, I was having issues accessing, UIActivityViewController in iOS as it was working well in Android.

I just tried to access with below code and everything started working like a charm.

```
let flutterViewController: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
```

Thank you @Richard.